# Enclosing multiple LaTeX documents

Tags: latex, append, tableofcontents

I am not sure if this question is suitable for superuser instead, but I'll ask anyway.

Currently I'm writing on my documentation for my final project. I must append several other LaTeX documents as enclosure. They must be mentioned in the first Table of Contents as alphabetical appendix. I tried the package `subfiles`, but the subsequent TOC´s are always empty exept in case of translating them alone.

Is there any other way to append multiple full documents with there own documentclass??

Comment: I couldn't find a `subpages` package on CTAN; did you mean `pdfpages` (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/)?  If you haven't tried it, you could take a look; I've never used it, but the manual says it has an `addtotoc` option.

Comment: sorry i miss-spelled it. its called subfiles.

Answer (score 2):

[subfiles](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) is a very simple package - it doesn't try to do anything other than manage the document-level macros.  You will need to issue an `\appendix` cs before each inclusion of a subfile.

Beware of the different latex documents sharing auxiliary files: if they do this, then subfiles will basically not work - you will be better off using the [pdfpages](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package that absz mentions.

**Postscript** If you want the subsidiary documents to have their own tables of contents, you have either to change their auxiliary files (at least, their .aux and .toc files), or switch to another mechanism.  Maybe [minitoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) will fit better?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you strip out the preamble of the other LaTeX documents and then use `\include` or `\input` depending on whether you want pagebreaks?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it is required to append the whole document with it´s own table of content.

Comment: If the subfiles have their own tables of contents, then subfiles won't work without hacking.  I've added a ps to my answer.